# How to locate an element on this page?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

I tried a lot to locate elements on this page with this [link](https://www.booking.com/hotel/eg/royal-tulip-alexandria.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaEOIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AqSOmI8GwAIB0gIkYThmZDc0NWMtNTA0YS00ZmI5LWFmZDMtOTkwYWI0MDNhMDU52AIF4AIB;sid=16c7a8afce639ab8d05c8311b384ec50;all_sr_blocks=78883120_334792541_2_1_0;checkin=2022-04-01;checkout=2022-04-14;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;highlighted_blocks=78883120_334792541_2_1_0;hpos=1;matching_block_id=78883120_334792541_2_1_0;no_rooms=1;req_adults=2;req_children=0;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;sr_pri_blocks=78883120_334792541_2_1_0__112600;srepoch=1642465068;srpvid=af0c0214b97f013b;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl)

ALL I want to do is to select "1 queen bed" or "1 double large bed" and then select amount from the drop down list then press, I'll reserve button.

But I totally failed trying all of these:-

1. using Action --> moveToElement --> perform()
2. using JS Execution --> scrollToView, scrollBy(0,100) for example to make the page scroll down
3. using all types of locators (ID, xPaths, cssSelectors, names) but always an error message that Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath- By.id .. etc.
4. tried to search for an iFrame but I didn't find but I think there are some but not related to the locators I want
5. Thread.sleep() to wait for a time if the element is not loaded on the web page.

I am using Selenium JAVA TestNG

so in the page I write this function:-

Page class I write this function :-

```
private By btnBed = By.xpath("(//i[@class='bicon bicon-double'])[1]");

     public void clickBed(){
//        JavascriptExecutor exe = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//        exe.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
    click(btnBed);
}
```

In my Test I write this:-

```
hotelPage.clickBed();
```

Error message:-

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that this page was opened in a new tab so the code can't locate any elements on the screen.
So I just switch tabs, the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> ALL I want to do is to select "1 queen bed" or "1 double large bed"

I inspecting the DOM on the link you provided, I see that it is radio button that you might want to select. Try locate the radio element button something like this

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="bedPreference_78883120" data-bed-type="">
```

Locate by name

```
By.name("bedPreference_78883120")
```

then perform the click.

Comment: same Error "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='bedPreference_78883120']"}"

Comment: Glad you found the solution. I was not able to get back to you on this, sorry.